# Group/count by part of a field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this

```
{"foo" : "abc-123", more fields.... }
{"foo" : "abc-456", more fields.... }
{"foo" : "cde-000", more fields.... }
{"foo" : "cde-555", more fields.... }
{"foo" : "else-9991234", more fields.... }
```

and want to group and count by the first part of `foo`:

```
{
    "abc": 2,
    "cde": 2,
    "else": 1
}
```

I thought about using aggregation framework for this, but I'm unsure how to extract the first part:

```
myColl.aggregate([
     $project: { firstPart: { ???? '$foo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pity that you need to split like this otherwise you could be using the $substr operator in the aggregation pipeline.

But since you need this function you can use mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce() {
    function() {
        var parts = this.foo.split("-");
        emit( parts[0], 1 );
    },
    function(key,values){
        return values.length;
    },
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Anything sent to the reducer counts the "values" in the array, anything with only one key by-passes the reducer, but we already returned the count of 1.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible to do with mongo. Eventually you have to split a string and group by the first part.

If I were you, I would rather modify your schema to add new field `foo1` which will be the first part of the string. You can do this with [foreach](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(el){
  // here split your el['foo'] and update the el with new `foo1` which will have your first part
})
```

After that you can easily use your aggregation framework.

Comment: thanks! Do you think it would be possible to use map-reduce instead of AF for that? Adding a new field would be complicated in my workflow...